# Spring MVC Model choking on ArrayList

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a generic Controller such that it handles programmatic declarations of js/css files, expressed as an ArrayList which is then added to the Model & pushed out to jsp.

The problem is that everything works until I add a filepath to the additionalJsFilePath List, at which I get a blank page (nothing, no html tags) in the browser.

Relevant code as follows:

*LoginController.java (extends BaseController)*

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
    doInitialRenditions();

    this.addJsFilePath("../jquery.min.js"); // THIS LINE BREAKS IT
    /*
    this.addJsFilePath("../jquery.otherfile.js");
    this.addJsFilePath("../xxxx.login.js");
    */
    doFinalRenditions(model);

    model.addAttribute("jsFile",  "../jquery.min.js");
    return "login";

}
```

*BaseController.java*

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

public List<String> additionalJsFilePaths;
public List<String> additionalCssFilePaths;

protected void init(){
    additionalJsFilePaths= new ArrayList<String>();
    additionalCssFilePaths= new ArrayList<String>();
}

protected void doInitialRenditions(){
    init();
}

protected void addJsFilePath(String path){
    additionalJsFilePaths.add(path);
}

protected void addCssFilePath(String path){
    additionalCssFilePaths.add(path);
}

protected void doFinalRenditions(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("jsFiles",  additionalJsFilePaths);
    model.addAttribute("cssFiles", additionalCssFilePaths);
}
}
```

I haven't even put in any code to access the *jsFiles* List within the .jsp so the problem is with the above two files. Just the fact that I populate the ArrayList is enough to break it. Also: the same thing happens with all the BaseController code in the LoginController, so don't think it's some dumb error with inheritance.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ... sort of. Nothing wrong with the operation of the code as such (ignoring for a moment the question of whether or not to do the js/css thing as above. The choke was in fact swapfile usage on the laptop thanks to JVM (though it took your very appropriate reminder to implement logging to figure that out). Cheers for your time & sorry for red herring. A

Answer (score 1):

Annoations are not inherited so LoginController is not a controller, you can inherit from a base class, but each subclass (each individual controller) needs to be annotated..

Also this sounds like avery bad idea

```
such that it handles programmatic declarations of js/css files
```

Separate your view and controller logic - MVC. Declare and map static resources in your config file.

Check you server logs(turn on logging).

For basic exception handling, which it sounds lik eyou need, you shoul dthink abotu adding something like this to your basecontrollerr

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String myExceptionHandler(final Exception e) {
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        final String strStackTrace = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
        logger.error(strStackTrace); // send to logger first
        emailService.sendAlertMail(strStackTrace);
        return "exception"; // default friendly excpetion message for user
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but LoginController is annotated, I purposely didn't reproduce the entire class here for clarity. As I stated in the original question, it works until the list item is added, hence the problem cannot be with spring not picking up the Controller. As to MVC logic: yes, of course where the resources are truly static (ie, common across all pages) - here, however, we're adding stuff which is unique to an individual page.

Comment: @tacticAl The annotation on basecontroller is redundant then. "we're adding stuff which is unique to an individual page" - don't do it in the controller if it is view/display logic, it goes completely against the architectural pattern MVC which you just said you agreed with. Also, you have a lot of logic to just add one model attribute, which itself shouldn't be done.

Comment: _Also, you have a lot of logic to just add one model attribute, which itself shouldn't be done._ I leave you to draw the obvious conclusion about how many attributes *will* be added when this thing does everything it's supposed to. We're getting sidetracked here. The issue is the ArrayList problem - server logs are silent on that.

Comment: the process of adding an attribute to the model is a simple one, your code makes it complex. Again, these css/js incldues really shouldn't be carried out in the controller.  Step through the code using your debugger. Server logs are silent ? They shouldn't be, you need to fix that too.

Comment: Solved ... sort of. Nothing wrong with the operation of the code as such (ignoring for a moment the question of whether or not to do the js/css thing as above. The choke was in fact swapfile usage on the laptop thanks to JVM (though it took your very appropriate reminder to implement logging to figure that out). Cheers for your time. A